# Avoid elements to move separately on browser resize in a React Form

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm struggling with the following form done in React:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
import { Container, Row, Col, InputGroup, Button, FormControl, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

const images = [
    {
        original: '/assets/images/products/colgantes.png',
        thumbnail: '/assets/images/products/colgantes@0.25x.png',
    },
    {
        original: '/assets/images/products/corazones.png',
        thumbnail: '/assets/images/products/corazones@0.25x.png',
    },
    {
        original: '/assets/images/products/take-me-to-the-beach.png',
        thumbnail: '/assets/images/products/take-me-to-the-beach@0.25x.png',
    },
];


class DetailedProduct extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <Container fluid>
                    <Row >
                        <Col md={{ span: 4, offset: 3 }} sm={{ span: 12, offset: 0}} >
                            <ImageGallery
                                    items={images}
                                    showNav=""
                                    showFullscreenButton=""
                                    showBullets=""
                                    showPlayButton=""
                                    thumbnailPosition="left"
                            />
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={3} sm={12} className="text-xs-center text-md-left" >
                            <h1>Product</h1>
                            <h3>$500</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text from the printing and typeseting industrys</p>

                            <Form>
                                <Row >
                                    <Col sm={12} md={8} >
                                        <Form.Group controlId="color" >
                                            <Form.Label>Color</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Control as="select" custom>
                                                <option>Rojo</option>
                                                <option>Negro</option>
                                                <option>Azul</option>
                                            </Form.Control>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                    </Col>

                                    <Col sm={12} md={4} className="inline-block">
                                        <Form.Group controlId="cantidad" >
                                            <Form.Label>Cantidad</Form.Label>
                                            <InputGroup >
                                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                                    <Button variant="outline-secondary"  >+</Button>
                                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                                <FormControl
                                                    placeholder="1"
                                                    aria-label="quantity"
                                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon2"

                                                />
                                                <InputGroup.Append>
                                                    <Button variant="outline-secondary" >-</Button>
                                                </InputGroup.Append>
                                            </InputGroup>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>

                            </Form>

                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>

            </>
        );
    }
}


export default DetailedProduct;
```

The problem I have is that when I resize the Browser Window, the appended buttons in the input, start to move down to a different row separately, breaking the [+ 1 -] block. I've tried applying different CSS to the form group but I can't find a way to tighten them together so that if they move, they move in a block and the following thing doesn't happen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the rule for the minimum size:

```
min-width: 150px;
```

150px is an example size.
Unfortunately I don't know the width size that input should have.

To the class that contains the three elements, input-group, in that case. I advise you to add a class and apply additional styles to that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was able to fix it by using the right flex column sizes for the scren resolution,  sm={12} md={6} lg={4} - That did the trick